# Where should I save the phpMyAdmin connection file (written in Notepad++, i.e. index.php, connect.php)?

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, phpmyadmin

I am building a website for my own and I want to connect the database to the site. The purpose of connecting DB is adding "posting comment and reply" functionality in my site.

However, I have XAMPP installed in my system.

Now I wrote the php code (in notepad++) to connect the mySQLdatabse (I already have created a database) to my website so that I can manipulate the data inserted in database. I will insert data, delete data, update data etc.

Now my question: what should be the path for those .php files (written in notepad++) in which I wrote the code for connection things happen? In which folder I should save the files? Please see my [Attachment](https://s.yimg.com/hd/answers/i/d7ba51cbd6ff47ce825b7d8a46bf34cd_A.jpeg?a=answers&mr=0&x=1408808187&s=9b8116714ec6ea125022ef9c34f56b30).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can save them into xampp/htdocs/yourproject/yourFile.php

in another example `xampp/htdocs/yourproject/connect.php`

all files what you want to run in xampp should b in `htdocs` directory.

in htdocs there is your root directory `yourSite` and all files you should place in your root directory whatever you name it.

**updated**

your `connect.php` should be in your root `yoursite/db/connect.php` directory.